# How to define a global error handler in gRPC python

Tags: python, error-handling, interceptor, grpc-python

Im trying to catch any exception that is raised in any servicer so I can make sure that I only propagate known exceptions and not unexpected ones like ValueError, TypeError etc.

I'd like to be able to catch any raised error, and format them or convert them to other errors to better control the info that is exposed.

I don't want to have to enclose every servicer method with try/except.

I've tried with an interceptor, but im not able to catch the errors there.

Is there a way of specifying an error handler for the grpc Server? like what you do with flask or any other http server?

Answer (score 3):

gRPC Python currently don't support server-side global error handler. The interceptor won't execute the server handler inside the `intercept_service` function, so there is no way to try/except.

Also, I found the gRPC Python server interceptor implementation is different from what they proposed original at [L13-Python-Interceptors.md#server-interceptors](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/361846400834164d21c12ca6cf60e8cbf501d6cd/L13-Python-Interceptors.md#server-interceptors). If the implementation stick to the original design, we can use interceptor as global error handler easily with `handler` and `request`/`request_iterator`.

```
# Current Implementation
intercept_service(self, continuation, handler_call_details)

# Original Design
intercept_unary_unary_handler(self, handler, method, request, servicer_context)
intercept_unary_stream_handler(self, handler, method, request, servicer_context)
intercept_stream_unary_handler(self, handler, method, request_iterator, servicer_context)
intercept_stream_stream_handler(self, handler, method, request_iterator, servicer_context)
```

Please submit a feature request issue to https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues.

Comment: well, I ended up coding a meta class, that inspects the servicers implementation, and wraps the servicers methods, so i can get in the middle and catch any exceptions that might occur.
Same for the intercepting the metadata and having a global store for the request, like flask does. 
Interceptors as they are now don't really satisfy what one would expect from a "middleware" so you end up having to implement your on middeware logic.

Comment: That's a smart hack! I hope I can up vote for comment :)

Comment: @Sebastian can you share part/all of the implementation Sebastian?

Comment: @KevinS we are in the process of open sourcing that solution, probably not a full blown library but at least a public one. I'll post the link when is available

Comment: great, yes please reply to this comment and I'll see it in my inbox.  Thanks!

Comment: @Sebastian is there any sample code you could provide for error handling?

Comment: An example for a meta-class solution similar to what was suggested in the comments above can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59649149/1629696

Answer (score 2):

As some of the previous comments suggested, I tried the meta-class approach which works quite well.

Attached is a simple example to demonstrate how to intercept the grpc calls.
You could extend this by providing the metaclass a list of decorators which you could apply on each function.

Also, it would be wise to be more selective regarding the methods you apply the wrapper to. A good option would be to list the methods of the autogenerated base class and only wrap those.

```
from types import FunctionType
from functools import wraps


def wrapper(method):
    @wraps(method)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        # do stuff here
        return method(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped


class ServicerMiddlewareClass(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, class_dict):
        new_class_dict = {}

        for attribute_name, attribute in class_dict.items():
            if isinstance(attribute, FunctionType):
                # replace it with a wrapped version
                attribute = wrapper(attribute)

            new_class_dict[attribute_name] = attribute

        return type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, new_class_dict)


# In order to use
class MyGrpcService(grpc.MyGrpcServicer, metaclass=ServicerMiddlewareClass):
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you :)

```
def _wrap_rpc_behavior(handler, fn):
    if handler is None:
        return None

    if handler.request_streaming and handler.response_streaming:
        behavior_fn = handler.stream_stream
        handler_factory = grpc.stream_stream_rpc_method_handler
    elif handler.request_streaming and not handler.response_streaming:
        behavior_fn = handler.stream_unary
        handler_factory = grpc.stream_unary_rpc_method_handler
    elif not handler.request_streaming and handler.response_streaming:
        behavior_fn = handler.unary_stream
        handler_factory = grpc.unary_stream_rpc_method_handler
    else:
        behavior_fn = handler.unary_unary
        handler_factory = grpc.unary_unary_rpc_method_handler

    return handler_factory(fn(behavior_fn,
                              handler.request_streaming,
                              handler.response_streaming),
                           request_deserializer=handler.request_deserializer,
                           response_serializer=handler.response_serializer)


class TracebackLoggerInterceptor(grpc.ServerInterceptor):

    def intercept_service(self, continuation, handler_call_details):
        def latency_wrapper(behavior, request_streaming, response_streaming):

            def new_behavior(request_or_iterator, servicer_context):
                try:
                    return behavior(request_or_iterator, servicer_context)
                except Exception as err:
                    logger.exception(err, exc_info=True)
            return new_behavior

        return _wrap_rpc_behavior(continuation(handler_call_details),    latency_wrapper)
```