# how to catch GRPC python errors in globaly

Tags: python-3.x, grpc

i'm new to GRPC servers.

is there are any way we can define a global error handler to catch all rpc errors ?

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52608502/how-to-define-a-global-error-handler-in-grpc-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a global error handler in gRPC python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52608502/how-to-define-a-global-error-handler-in-grpc-python)

Comment: @StevenZamborsky nop, i tried it. but it's not working